# Convert time (eg 15:00) to UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, function, date, unix-timestamp

Is it possible to convert a time (for example "15:00") to UNIX timestamp using PHP?

Unfortunately, my source of this data doesn't include the rest of the date/time data (date etc.)

I know which timezone the the time relates to, so could this be done? Is their a pre-existing function that will do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since 1 January 1970 so without a date you cannot convert a time to a Unix timestamp.

Comment: No date means no timestamp

Comment: The only way you could do this is under the assumption that the time you're being provided is 15:00 during a current day/date (eg. today), otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice all.

I should have said that given the source of my data, and my intended use, one can assume that the time refers to the current day. Having said that, rmontagud's suggest would be ideal

I do however acknowledge the fact that the UNIX timestamp refers to a time in relation to a specific day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) might work for you.. As @ceejayoz points it's not possible to create a reliable timestamp without more data. The following example assumes every date relates to current day

```
<?php
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '15:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
echo $d->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Perfect, this will work in my scenario as I am able to assume that the time refers to the current day.

Answer (score 1):

Without the date, it's not possible to do this accurately.

In areas with daylight savings, for example, 15:00 local could correspond to 10:00 UTC, or 9:00 UTC, depending on the date.

Answer (score -2):

No, You cannot as the idea of date is present in the Unix timestamp. A Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since 1 January 1970.

As PHP is quite `forgiving`, you can still use the function strtotime.

strtotime("15:00")

PHP assumes the current date/today.

For more information, please see the following link.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Ỳeah, I had tried this as well, assuming that PHP would automatically use the current date, only to discover my assumption was incorrect. Hence this question.